# Resizing of image on mobile

Tags: html, mobile, user-agent, image-resizing

I have static HTML pages for mobile display. The article may contain the image of different sizes. The problem is I dodn't know how to resize this image depending on the mobile user agent.

Can any body help me in resolving this?

The content : - 
<img src="/img/2011/11/08-kingfisher-flight-land.jpg" style="border: 0px none;" alt="Kingfisher" title="Kingfisher" hspace="5" vspace="5" >


New Delhi, Nov 8: An unofficial source informed that Kingfisher soon will cancel minimum 31 flights daily till Nov 19, though reason behind cancellation of flights have not yet been clarified.
Citing the news, many started reiterating about the financial knots in the Kingfisher airlines led by Vijay Mallya. .......
      This is actually for mobile served page. Since I don't know the device, I am not giving any width and height. Is there any way without setting the width and height, I will be able to resize the image???

Comment: Show some relevant HTML code for your image. Are you using an IMG tag? Do you already know how to use different CSS files for different browsers/devices? You can style the width/height properties of an IMG tag to define the displayed size

Comment: Thanks musefan, for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone supports Javascript,

You can use Javascript to determine the phone agent.

Here's a link to more information
http://webdesign.about.com/od/mobile/a/detect-mobile-devices.htm